# Connecting to postgres from node fails, but works in other environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, psql, linode

I have recently created a [managed linode database](https://www.linode.com/docs/products/databases/managed-databases/) in postgres. I managed to connect to it through a command line client (psql), through a gui db manager (datagrip) and also through a python script. When I try to connect to the database through node however, it fails with the following error:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "my.current.ip", user "linpostgres", database
```

The full error:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "my.current.ip", user "linpostgres", database "postgres", no encryption
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/handris/Projects/budapest-property-price/db2/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/handris/Projects/budapest-property-price/db2/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/handris/Projects/budapest-property-price/db2/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/handris/Projects/budapest-property-price/db2/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
  length: 161,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '552',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
}
```

Note, that this is a managed database, so as far as I can tell, I cannot edit the configuration for the database (the pg_hba.conf file).
Also, Linode requires me to add the ip address to the 'access controls' from which I am going to access the database. It is added.

From node, I tried connecting using two libraries:

- [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)
- [postgresql-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgresql-client)

Both of them gives the same error from above.

Here is an exmaple connection that works for local servers, but fails for the remote linode database:

```
import { Connection } from 'postgresql-client';

  const connection = new Connection({
    host: 'lin-****-****-pgsql-primary.servers.linodedb.net',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'linpostgres',
    password: '***********',
    database: 'postgres',
  });

  await connection.connect();
  const result = await connection.query('select * from table;');
```

Any idea why node has this error?

Comment: Based on the error message, it appears that the server refused to proceed without encryption, while node refuses to use encryption.  The other clients you tested are willing to use encryption, which is why they succeeded.